# Strange behavior during JavaScript cookie deletion

Tags: javascript, cookies, timeout

I'm trying to delete cookies with JavaScript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(document.cookie);
document.cookie='SAP_NWGW_DEV_SESSION=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.e.corpintra.net; path=/';
console.log(document.cookie);    
</script>
```

Corresponding to the console output it seems like the cookies are gone, but after executing 'document.cookies' directly in the console I can see the cookies again.

My current solution is to run the code as function within 
'window.setTimeout(theFunction, 1000)'. Does someone know a better solution (without a hard defined timeout)?

Comment: does really no one has any idea?